# Call a method continuously when button is in pressed state

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am trying to call a method continuously as long as button is pressed.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
method();
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/button_send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Comment: Do you want if you press button the method run continually

Comment: yes as long as the button is in pressed state

Comment: you can do it in thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a while loop in the method() which you want to execute. The while will exit when the `ACTION_UP` is received.
Something like this will work:

```
boolean pressed = true;  
private void method() {  
    while(pressed) {  
        //Code  
    }  
}
```

Set the boolean pressed false when you get `ACTION_UP`.

Comment: yes ACTION_CANCEL can also be used to break the loop

Comment: i think app will stuck at this stage { while(pressed) { //Code } }

Comment: Your method should execute on a background thread and not on the UI thread because UI thread is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement onTouchListener and overide onTouch() method with switch case.

```
float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

      return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: onTouch events are not continuously called.It will be only called when the user performs any of the Down,Up or Move actions. This will not solve the problem

Comment: i don't think ACTION_DOWN will be called on a touch.

Comment: Both ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP will get called for a touch

Comment: It will be called on onTouch().

Answer (score 0):

use can use OnLongClickListener()

Comment: This will not solve the problem as it will be called only once if the user keeps the button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi use onTouchListener function it will help to do the continues process when you press as long as the button

```
Button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

        // Do what you want
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

});

Comment: This will not work as onTouch events get called till the time user is changing the touch coordinates. For a continued press this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this one..

            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    maintainView = v;
                    hidingevent.onTouchEvent(event);
                    if (ViewerActivity.sClick == 1) {
                        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            call your method();

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
call your method();

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:


                                       int index = event.getActionIndex();
                        int action = event.getActionMasked();
                        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
                        switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
call your method();
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
call your method();

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:


                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class OTL extends Handler implements OnTouchListener {

    private int cnt;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            sendEmptyMessage(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch ACTION_DOWN ");
        } else
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            removeMessages(0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "run your method here " + cnt++);
        sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

testing code:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Button button = new Button(this);
ll.addView(button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new OTL());
setContentView(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is touch and hold listener for performing task .
Add some delay to over queue the touch events

```
  @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        class FrontTouchHandler extends Handler implements View.OnTouchListener {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    removeMessages(0);
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    //perform task here 
                    sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 125);
                }
            }
        }
```